# How to make an IF function in Excel to sum the amounts guests that show between certain times?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Picture of mock data in Excel Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0gWF.png) I'm currently making an excel document for the company I work for, and I can't seem to figure out how to format this cell, to sum up, the number of guests that show for each function within a certain time frame.
We have 3 separate 'shows' being:

Show 1 - is between times 10:00 am and 1:30 pm
Show 2 - is between 1:45 pm and 5:00 pm
Show 3 - is between 5:15 pm and 8:15 pm

There can be multiple parties in each show so let's say there is a party at 10:45 am with 20 people, and a party at 12:00 pm with 67 people. The guest counts for party 1 and party 2 would be listed in Column E between cells E8 to E15. Both these parties would be within Show 1 and would need to sum the cells in Column E that fall under the times that are held in Column A between cells A8-A15.

I'm not sure if this sounds confusing or not. I could always upload a picture of my excel file and highlight the cells I'm talking about so you could get a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Thank you so much for anyone that can help me with this, it means a lot and would help me with multiple excel files I'm working on that require the function that is used to solve this.

Comment: Can you Mock up some data and [edit] your question to include that mocked up data.  Sounds like SUMIFS or COUNTIFS will work

Comment: Agree with @Scott Craner - It might be helpful to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Alright, I just added in a picture of the excel doc with some mock data - I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

## SUMIF (Different Formulas Version)

I have used the following time format in range `A8:A15`:

```
h:mm AM/PM
```

and the following three formulas in range `D18:D20`:

```
=SUMIF(A$8:A$15,"<=13:30",E$8:E$15)
=SUM(E$8:E$15)-D18-D20
=SUMIF(A$8:A$15,">=17:15",E$8:E$15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a pretty handy function called `SUMIFS()` which would work nicely here.

As an example, I've created this formula which will tell you the number of guests (from column E) whose party arrived between the times (from column A) for Show 1: `=SUMIFS(E:E, A:A, ">=10:00", A:A, "<=13:30")`

We can extend this formula without much effort to review more than one time, and even label the outputs, ie: `="Show 1: " & SUMIFS(E:E, A:A, ">=10:00", A:A, "<=13:30") & ", Show 2: " & SUMIFS(E:E, A:A, ">=13:45", A:A, "<=17:00") & ...` etc.

I hope this helps you, welcome to SO

Comment: For some reason the SUMIFS will not work if it just says 12:00 PM, it must say 12:00:00 PM - is there a way to make it work for 12:00 PM or do will I have to edit each time to say 12:00:00 after pasting in the Data?

Comment: It's hard to say, that formula was cut & paste from Excel and it worked there. Could the cell formats be leading you awry? Try to make sure the entire range A:A is formatted as short time, and try again. Also, times in Excel may be different based on internationalization settings.. just a theory

Comment: Yeah everything is formatted as short time hh:mm I am so confused on why it would be doing that. If I add in the 00 on 12:00 PM so it says 12:00:00 PM it will work but not when I just paste the data from the other excel sheet and it just says 12:00 PM. I don't even know why that would effect it.